# Difference between Application Not Responding and Unfortunately <Appname> has stopped in Android?

Tags: android

Since I am new to Android, I want to know what is the main cause behind these two issues and how can I avoid them in my application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Application not responding" means the application isn't responsive to UI events on its main thread and the system is giving the user a choice to stop the app or let it continue. This typically happens when you do too much work on the UI thread that should be moved to other background threads. The process is still running, it just isn't responsive to user input (like touch events).

"Unfortunately  has stopped" means the app actually crashed with an uncaught exception at runtime and the process was killed.

Comment: How can I avoid them in my app ?

Comment: @PradipShenolkar You avoid the first by not doing long-running tasks (or tasks of indeterminate length) on the main thread. Basically, any nontrivial code that doesn't directly touch the UI probably belongs on a background thread. You avoid the second by thoroughly testing your app and your code and fixing bugs before releasing the app.

Comment: @PradipShenolkar To fix crashes, learn how to view your app's logcat and how to read a stack trace.  Crashes in the logs will include the phrase `FATAL EXCEPTION`.  Search this site, there are lots of good answers already.

Comment: @PradipShenolkar Multithreading is a rather involved topic. If you aren't familiar with it yet, _Efficient Android Threading_ is one book that covers threading concepts and ties it into what the Android SDK provides. There are probably any number of online resources as well.